# Array not being passed to query in knex

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I am passing an array of ids from a get query to a knex whereIn function but they are going missing.

```
if(query.cols){
  var cols = query.cols.map(Number);
  console.log(cols)
  search.whereIn('collection_id', cols)
}
```

I am mapping them to Integers for the query. The console log is...

```
[ 77, 66 ]
```

But the debug shows the query as...

```
...and "collection_id" in (?, ?)
```

What have I missed?

Comment: Actually, I now see in the bindings that the values are there, however, still strings. 

bindings: [ '77', '66', '1', '100' ],

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Edit**:
This solution is for a previous version of Knex ([v0.12.1](https://github.com/knex/knex/releases/tag/0.12.1))

The current documentation for raw bindings can be found here: https://knexjs.org/guide/raw.html#raw-parameter-binding

**Old**:
The values show as strings because `knex` requires that arrays be passed as arguments within a containing array. From the documentation for [raw bindings](http://knexjs.org/#Raw-Bindings):

> Note that due to ambiguity, arrays must be passed as arguments within a containing array.

> ```
> knex.raw('select * from users where id in (?)', [1, 2, 3]);
> ```

```
// Error: Expected 3 bindings, saw 1
```

> ```
> knex.raw('select * from users where id in (?)', [[1, 2, 3]])
> ```

```
Outputs:
select * from users where id in (1, 2, 3)
```

You can fix this by passing the `cols` array within an array itself:

```
if (query.cols) {
  var cols = query.cols.map(Number);
  console.log(cols)
  search.whereIn('collection_id', [cols])
}
```

Comment: This solution of passing an array of array is not working for me. 
I am passing it in my query like this: 
let sql = "AND diu.rebel_inventory_code IN (?) ";

This is my params array. Here, obj.inv_code is an array. 
let paramas_array = [obj.inv_code];
let data = await knex.raw(sql, paramas_array);
resolve(data.rows);

But the query is not returning any data. Can ayone help, why it is not working for me. 
I have only written only the relevant part of the query, not the whole query.

Comment: @Brainless-Coder The solution provided by chiragsrvstv uses the updated API from Knex and should help solve the problem.

Answer (score 10):

According to Knex docs on raw parameter binding, we need to add `?` for every element in our array that would be binded to the query:

> Since there is no unified syntax for array bindings, instead you need to treat them as multiple values by adding ? directly in your query.
> https://knexjs.org/guide/raw.html#raw-parameter-binding

```
const myArray = [1,2,3]
knex.raw('select * from users where id in (' + myArray.map(_ => '?').join(',') + ')', [...myArray]);
// query will become: select * from users where id in (?, ?, ?) with bindings [1,2,3]
```

Comment: well...that was weird since `?` is not valid postgres syntax

Comment: @Madeo and that is exactly why knex uses the question mark. If it were valid postgres syntax, there would be interference between postgres and knex

Answer (score 0):

All Credits  to @chiragsrvstv

Instead of knex.row I used whereRaw here is the code

```
const whereClause= [ 75, 76 ]


//if array length is 0 then have this
//`select * from "users" where id!=0`
     if(whereClause.length <= 0) {
            whereClause= [ 0 ]
        }
    
        console.log(  knex('users').whereRaw("id!="+whereClause.map(_ => '?').join(' and id!='), [...whereClause]).toString())
```