# How do I utilize PSQL parameter binding in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, parameters, psql

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN ($1), [[2,5,7,101]];
```

I've also tried:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN ($1), ([2,5,7,101]);
```

But I get this syntax error:

```
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: ...table WHERE id IN ($1),[[2,5,7...
```

How can I utilize parameter binding?

Comment: How exactly are you interfacing with Postgresql? Something like Sequelize?

Comment: Also for what you're trying to do, `= ANY` might be better than `IN`; does the same thing but the right-hand side is an array instead of a syntactic list that isn't a single value.

Comment: I am using using Knex.js

Comment: Then I think you should be using [raw queries](https://knexjs.org/guide/raw.html#raw-queries) if you want to do straight SQL.

Comment: According to Knex docs on raw parameter binding, we need to add ? for every element in our array that would be binded to the query
See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65210654/19837930
```await trx.raw(`DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN (${ids.map(() => '?').join(',')})`, [...ids]);```

Comment: Yes, and in my experience it's easier to do that with `= ANY` because the right-hand side is a single array value (in Postgresql).  For `IN` to work, you need to bind each value in the list individually.  What you suggest might work however, and if so then it's fine; in my experience the query plans for `IN` and `= ANY` (at least in simple cases like this) are pretty much identical.